# Swift CreateML error while trying to train data model. Any input is greatly appreciated

Tags: swift, csv, coreml, createml

I'm doing a tutorial on how to create a Machine Learning Data model using Swift CoreML & CreateML. I'm getting a weird error when trying to load the training data into the MLTextClassifier object from a .csv file.

What I'm expecting it to do is simply train the classifier object and show my evaluation results on how well it learned based on the data given, but instead I'm getting the error shown below. Any input is greatly appreciated.

I've made sure my code is free of typos and that the .csv file path is correct. I've also read Apple's documentation and followed it accordingly for this setup. I've also looked online for a solution and found nothing.

The console shows that my csv file is loading, and that the "randomSplit()" function is correctly parsing the data, but once I try to create the "sentimentClassifier" thats where the error appears.

Here's my code:

```
import Cocoa
import CreateML

let data = try MLDataTable(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: "/path/file.csv"))

let (trainingData, testingData) = data.randomSplit(by: 0.8, seed: 5)

let sentimentClassifier = try MLTextClassifier(trainingData: trainingData, textColumn: "text", labelColumn: "sentiment")

let evaluationMetrics = sentimentClassifier.evaluation(on: testingData, textColumn: "text", labelColumn: "sentiment")

let evaluationAccuracy = (1.0 - evaluationMetrics.classificationError) * 100
```

Here's the error:

> **error: Couldn't lookup symbols:**
>
> **static CreateML.MLTextClassifier.defaultParameters.getter : CreateML.MLTextClassifier.ModelParameters**

Comment: I was getting this error earlier as well, using a beta version of Xcode. Using a different version of XCode (in my case, a non-beta version; Xcode 10.3) worked fine.

Comment: I’m in beta as well, so it sounds like it’s just a beta bug. I’m going leave this post open for a few days to see if anyone else has anymore details on the issue, then I’ll close it as solved. Thank you for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

`let evaluationMetrics   = sentimentClassifier.evaluation(on: testingData, textColumn: "text", labelColumn: "class")`

Enter this code instead. Hopefully this will work.